# Plaintext on iCloud with Version Control using iOS?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to edit my data in plain text files
under some kind of version control and access them via iOS?

Comment: Versioning is not something in iCloud.  Though Time Machine “could” technically facilitate versioning but not in an efficient or meaningful way. If you want versioning, you need a tool like Git or subversion.  Git has a cloud service you might find useful